# Capistrano git on remote server needs password

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy using Capistrano. My remote server accesses github using an ssh passphrase. The Capistrano "cap deploy:update" command is able to access Github, and then to log in to the remote server, and I can see the command it sets up:

```
git clone -q <github link>
```

and then, on the remote server, it doesn't seem to know that it has to ask for an SSH passphrase. (So I get Permission denied (publickey) error)

I tried some suggested solutions, like ssh-options in the config/deploy.rb file, but they didn't work. How can I get Capistrano to know to ask for the SSH passphrase, on the remote server? This is the one I tried:

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

Comment: Can you paste the SSH options you've tried so far?  I suspect you've missed one.

Comment: @DaveSteinberg, thanks. I just pasted it in. I put it into the config/deploy file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be a lot better off if you added a GitHub deploy key to your remote server. Password-based authentication does not work very well with Capistrano.